# React Native insert one component into another

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to "inject" one RN component into another in a specific place.
Say I have this component:

```
const Original = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      {InsertChildComponentHere}
    </View>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>I am a child component</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think a clearer picture of your attempt will benefit this question and the community. Your question is likely to get a answer of -> just put <ChildComponent /> at the location

Comment: That's true. I wasn't specific enough regarding my requirement for it to exist inside a HOC.  I was trying to clear up and just write what I absolutely needed. And honestly, now that I see the complexity of doing this inside a HOC, it makes more sense to just import the component I need wherever I need it, instead of messing with adding this "import" functionality. It will be just as verbose or even more to handle this inside the HOC (wrapper) than inside the different components themselves directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject a Component into a other Component (HOC) your component has to accept "Component" as params. You can write it like this:

```
const Original = (Component) => {
  const newComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  };

  return newComponent;
};
```

to create the HOC you can write:

```
const MyComponent = withOriginal(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: I am trying to inject a component into another inside a HOC. I realize you can just import a component inside another and place it wherever you want, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can make it like a HOC.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should have been clearer from the start.